# Как реализовать парсер чтобы он не парсил повторяющиеся новости

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

Надо сделать чтобы парсер не парсил повторяющиеся новости.

Сам мой парсер парсит 10 ресурсов. И он парсит ссылку, заголовок, дату, контент новости, и после этого он заносит все данные в таблицу для новостей.

Идея моей реализации такая: Проверить url новости в БД. Если такая новость уже есть, то ее не надо добавлять. А если нету то добавить.

Вот структура моей таблицы для новостей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой код я написал. Дальше я не могу понять как сделать проверку на `url`

```
# < Цикл для вызова функции.
    for resource_link in resource_links:
        # < Запрос ссылок новостей из items.
        cursor.execute('SELECT `item_link`  FROM `items`')
        items_links = cursor.fetchall()


        item_page = get_html(resource_link)
        item_title = get_item_title(item_page,title_rule)
        item_datetime = get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule)
        item_text_content = get_text_content(item_page,text_rule,text1_rule)

        # < Запись новостей в БД.
        sql = "insert into item (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor=connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(item_text_content)))
        cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4')
        cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")
        cursor.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4")
        print('Запись в базу данных успешно завершена!')

connection.close()
```

**UPD** Вот такой код добавил:

```
 # < запись новостей в БД.
        items = cursor.execute('SELECT `item_link` FROM `items` WHERE `item_link` != "resource_link"')
        items_ver = cursor.fetchall()
        if items_ver == None:
            sql = "insert into test_item (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            cursor=connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(item_text_content)))
            print('Запись в базу данных успешно завершена!')
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как лучше реализовать парсер чтобы он не парсил повторяющиеся новости?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1016812/204271)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы проверить url на идентичность нужно перед занесением в бд новостей прописывать:

```
verif = cursor.execute('SELECT `item_link` FROM `items` WHERE `item_link` != "переменная с url новости которую мы проверяем"').fetchall()

if verif == None:
   #Добовляем статью
```

В коде возможны ошибки так как я писал пример.
None проверяет на пустоту переменную так как если она не пустая значит уже есть такая статья

Comment: Ваш код работает.Но некорректно то есть не добавляет новости

Comment: В моем примере после `if` я поставил коментарий  где должен находится ваш код который добавляет новость

Comment: Я так и сделал у меня стоит код insert'а.Я его добавил в выше.

Answer (score 2):

Поле item_link можно сделать [UNIQUE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/) полем, дубликаты не будут записываться.

Comment: Если вы посмотрите скриншот.То я так и сделал.Но видите ли после того как я сделал поле UNIQUE выходит такая ошибка pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'https://www.zakon.kz/4983020-v-izdatelstve-zheti-zhar-y-vyshlo.h' for key 'item_link'")